# What does "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))" do?

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

There is a common example loop used in the teaching of PHP Select queries and I was just writing a bit of code to select from a  table.  I had used this code before but never bothered to consider why it is written as so.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

}
```

My understanding is that a while loop is something that runs until the condition becomes false, sometimes using an incremental value and comparisons or what not.  In this case I'm not sure what is causing the loop to "stop looping"?  Initially I would see it as an infinite loop but maybe I'm not entirely sure what `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` might return each time the loop goes 'round.  Can someone please explain this to me?  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of assignment in PHP is the same as the value that has been assigned to the variable.  That is, the statement `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` has a "value" of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`.

`while` will loop until the condition is false, or more accurately, is `== false`.  Note that this is different from `=== false`.  Since, in PHP, `null == false`, the loop will continue until there are no more rows in the result returned from the MySQL database, as the function returns `null` when there are no more rows.

Comment: ok, so is there an incremental value in the loop?  In other words how does it know to return the next row in the table, rather than the same one repeatedly?

Comment: Its stored in `$result`.

Comment: Implicit in your answer, but to save time for anybody new being as slow as I was: the reason it is = rather than == (which is what one typically sees in a while line) is that is an assignment, not a comparison.